# Magento overriding an overridden controller?

Tags: magento

How can I override a controller which has been overridden in the community codepool? In my case its the `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`. The controller that overrides this does some stuff in the `postAction` function and then calls the parent, which is `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`. My override of `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` does not work because of that.

Do I have to override the overriding controller in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you override an already overridden controller, your controller will get executed first only if your module is alphabetically ahead of the module that has already overridden it. For instance if your module name starts with letter "A" and previous module starts with letter "B", in this case yours will be executed first. This is because when magento finds 2 or more modules overriding same class it will go with the one which was fetched first in alphabetical order. You can try that way.

Also check this: [overriding a magento block in multiple modules (and how to ignore the other ones)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161954/overriding-a-magento-block-in-multiple-modules-and-how-to-ignore-the-other-ones)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Codepool `canonot create issue in rewrite` ,there may  be any issues in your module.You need to check this.

Please check this link here you have find you to [rewrite controllers class](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/)